# Permanent accept of java certificate is not woring on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java, certificate, digital-signature

Usually when starting a signed Java Application - no matter if starting inside a browser as applet or via JNLP/JavaWebStart – there is a warning prompt notifying if to run the application.
On accepting I can tick a checkbox to accept for that publisher and location in general.

In the past with windows 7/8 this worked fine – but now on windows 10 it is not working – I always have to approve the application again.
(In the past the cert was added to the trusted Certificates:  Java Control Panel -> Security -> Manage Certificates: Trusted Certificates -> User)

Java 1.8u121-b13 & Windows 10.0.16299
And I'm using only a user account.

Maybe any new Windows 10 security restrictions?
Any Win 10 Group Policy that is restricting this?
Anybody got any reasons for that?

Edit: Yes it is again and again the same certificate - it is not added to the trusted certificates.

Comment: You mention it was done in the past, but have you confirmed, the certificate is still trusted?  Have you verified the prompt to accept the certificate, is for the same certificate, you trusted?  Edit your question.

Comment: The point that it is not added to the trusted certificates. In the past it was. Now I have to confirm each and every time - even wen ticking the checkbox